# Django - Get the list of items with a filter

Tags: python, django, algorithm, django-models, django-views

My Models:

```
Item:
    name
    desc

Type:
    name

Value:
    text
    type.ForeignKey(Type)
    item = ForeignKey(Item)
```

I had an initial list of types from table Type, assume t = [4,5,6]. Now I have to get a list of items have types are t. For example:

Data list of Value:

```
type  |  item
4        1
5        1
6        1
4        2
5        2
4        3
```

So, if t = [4,5,6], result I need that is `items = [<object: 1>]`

**UPDATE**:

t = [4,5] `items = [<object: 1>, <object: 2>]`

t = [4] `items = [<object: 1>, <object: 2>, <object: 3>]`

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: Му solution works exactly as you want (in update section too). Or it doesn't?

Comment: I'm gonna test :)
Thanks friend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure this is the best solution, but it works

```
from itertools import groupby

values = Value.objects.filter(type_id__in=t).values_list('type_id', 'item_id')
values = sorted(values, key=lambda x: x[1])

items = []
for key, group in groupby(values, lambda x: x[1]):
    types = [x[0] for x in group]
    if set(t).issubset(set(types)):
        items.append(key)
```

`items` will containd ids, not objects, but I don't think it can be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter through a many-to-many relation which Value is:

```
Item.objects.filter(value__type__id__in = [4, 5, 6])
```

Update: The above would work for an OR query, to find all items that has ANY of the specified types. To find all items that has ALL the types, you have to create an AND query by chaining filters:

```
q = Item.objects
for id in [4, 5, 6]:
    q = q.filter(value__type__id = id)
print q.all()
# or
q = reduce(lambda q, i: q.filter(value__type__id = i), [4, 5, 6], Item.objects)
print q.all()
```

Comment: And get items which have types [4], [4, 5], [5, 6] etc. But the task is different.